# How can I bind directives to custom components in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

So I am using [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com) with vue-cli and this is my current component code:

```
<template>
<div>
  <v-row>
    <v-col xl3 md3 xs12>
      <strong>{{field}}</strong>
    </v-col>
    <v-col xl9 md9 xs12>
      {{value}}
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
       data() {
           return {

           }
       },
       props: ['field', 'value']
    }
</script>
```

And I am using it in my templates like this

```
<template>
<two-column field="Some Field" value="Some Value"></two-column>
</template>

<script>
import TwoColumnRow from './vuetify_modifications/TwoColumnRow'
...
</script>
```

Now everything works perfectly but what if I want to make the grid sizes dynamic? Like for example I do with something like

`<two-column field="Some Field" value="Some Value" sizes="xl3 md3 xs12"></two-column>`

Is that possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you please put your example in JSFiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
<foo :sizes="{ xl3: '', md3: '', xs12: '' }"></foo>
```

And:

```
<template>
<div>
  <v-row>
    <v-col v-bind="sizes">
      <strong>{{field}}</strong>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
       props: {
           sizes: { type: Object, default: () => {} }
           // ...
       }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way I've been able to accomplish this is through the use of computed properties.

For simplicity of creating the example I've used colors to represent what is happening. Since it seems as through all you're really asking is how could you dynamically apply classes or value based conditions inside a component, this should work with some tweaks.

```js
const TwoColumnRow = Vue.component('two-column', {
  template: '#two-column-row-template',
  data: function() {
    return {}
  },
  props: ['field', 'value', 'colors'],
  computed: {
    colorList: function() {
      // Split the string of colors by space and return an array of values
      return this.colors.split(' ');
    }
  }
});

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app-container',
  data: {}
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app-container">
  <table>
    <two-column field="toast" value="cheese" colors="blue red"></two-column>
  </table>
</div>

<script type="x-template" id="two-column-row-template">
  <tr>
    <td v-bind:class="colorList[0]">{{field}}</td>
    <td v-bind:class="colorList[1]">{{value}}</td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

This runs, so you could insert some statements {{colorList}} inside the component to see what is being rendered.